Application Customizer in SharePoint 2019
I developed a SPFx Application Customizer app that let me inject css code in my site collection. Its very simple, its basically insert your css file to the header. Here is the code
    export default class HelloWorldApplicationCustomizer
  extends BaseApplicationCustomizer<IHelloWorldApplicationCustomizerProperties> {

  public onInit(): Promise<void> {
    Log.info(LOG_SOURCE, `Initialized ${strings.Title}`);

    console.log("Application Customizer Context", this.context)
    const cssUrl: string = this.properties.cssurl;
    if (cssUrl) {


        // inject the style sheet
        const head: any = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement;
        let customStyle: HTMLLinkElement = document.createElement("link");
        customStyle.href = `${this.context.pageContext.site.absoluteUrl}/${cssUrl}`;
        customStyle.rel = "stylesheet";
        customStyle.type = "text/css";
        head.insertAdjacentElement("beforeEnd", customStyle);
    }

    return Promise.resolve();
  }
}

When I do gulp serve, its being applied my target site. Its working fine as expect. The only thing is when I deploy the .sppkg file in my Tenant App Catalog and install it on my Site Collection, somehow the Application Customizer is not getting applied. The console log code is not even showing up in my console.
I dont have CDN or uses CDN so in my "write-manifest.json", I point it to my document library and deploy the "dist" file in the Document Library
Am I missing something? Any help would be awesome

